# Call to undefined method CI_Encrypt::sha1() saving password

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption, sha1

Hello Everyone I got this error when saving password on registration form **"A PHP Error was encountered**,Severity: Error | Message: Call to undefined method CI_Encrypt::sha1() | Filename: controllers/User.php | Line Number: 54 | Backtrace:"

and this is my code:

```
$userdata['password']   = $this->encrypt->sha1($this->input->post('password'));
```

Comment: Dont use sha1 for passwords. [RTM - See warning](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html): DO NOT use this or any other encryption library for user password storage! Passwords must be hashed instead, and you should do that via PHP’s own [Password Hashing extension](http://php.net/password).

Comment: Ok sir copy thanks for your reply..

Comment: With PHP use [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php), the pair are secure and easy to use.

When saving a password verifier just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `Argon2`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions with a ~100ms duration. The point is to make the attacker spend substantial of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: hello dude I ger it now thank you very much I removed my answer earlier because my repo is keep going down